# Error in installing setup

Tags: visual-studio, installshield

I made installer file by using install shield in visual studio 2012 , it works fine on my laptop . When i tried to install it on other pc it shows this error.

```
 Error 1309: Error read from file,then path of my installer 
 verify that file exist and you can access it
```

is any tool needed for it? I have .net 4 installed

Comment: If this was from a popup message, you'll want to try getting more context by creating and examining a verbose log.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused if the installer .zip/.msi file was placed in a folder that caused the paths of the files contained within it to exceed the Windows limit of 260 characters.

If the Windows character limit is exceeded, file names will be truncated during installation, so the installer cannot find them.

The solution could be to try with another path like "C:\Temp".